# Message can't be edited aiogram. Бот не может отредактировать сообщение

Tags: python, aiogram

Столкнулся с проблемой: бот не может отредактировать собственное сообщение (даже которое отправлено только что)

Вот код: (Суть в том, что по команде /start выходит сообщение с Inline клавиатурой, по нажатию на кнопку сообщение должно меняться на другое, но выходит ошибка)

```
@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(tx.start,parse_mode="Markdown", reply_markup=kb.startkb)
    @dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'startprofile')
    async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
        await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
        await message.edit_text(text=tx.user_profile,reply_markup=kb.backtostartkb)
```

Сама ошибка:

> aiogram.utils.exceptions.MessageCantBeEdited: Message can't be edited

Перепробовал практически все (менял message.edit_text на bot.edit_message_text и т.д.), но не помогало.

Comment: во первых вы пытаетесь редактировать сообщение пользователя, а во вторых когда изменяете reply_markup возникают проблемы

Answer (score 2):

У Вас обработчик для callback-кнопки в функции start лежит, зачем?

У класса `CallbackQuery` есть атрибут `message`, где и лежит сообщение, которое взаимодействует с кнопкой. Правильно должно быть так:

```py
@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(tx.start,parse_mode="Markdown", reply_markup=kb.startkb)


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'startprofile')
async def process_callback_button1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await callback_query.message.edit_text(text=tx.user_profile,reply_markup=kb.backtostartkb)
```